# UIImagePickerController does not free memory on device

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, uiimagepickercontroller

I use the UIImagePickerController to select the video or create a new one. My application takes 37 MB of memory on device. When I select or create a new video my application size increases by the size of the video. Even if I never use the video or just go away from the screen, or unload the application from memory, the size of the application on the device is much more than original. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I found only this article http://www.techbout.com/delete-documents-data-iphone-11719/

Answer (score 0):

Just set the imagepicker delegate to nil.

```
picker.delegate = nil;
```